# How to create in-paragraph enumerations in ConTeXt?

Tags: lists, context, enumerate, context-mkiv

The ConTeXt wiki article on [enumerations](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Enumerations) shows many solutions for creating an enumerated list, however, I see no examples for creating an in-paragraph enumeration, e.g.:

```
Five animals lived in the forest: (1) bears, (2) snakes, (3) fish, (4) birds, and (5) wolves.
```

How can I create in-paragraph enumerations in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `text` key:

```
\setupitemize [stopper=]
\starttext

Five animals lived in the forest:
\startitemize [n,text]
  \startitem
    bears,
  \stopitem
  \startitem
    snakes,
  \stopitem
  \startitem
    fish,
  \stopitem
  \startitem
    birds, and
  \stopitem
  \startitem
    wolves.
  \stopitem
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

Result:

[image: result]

The `stopper` key is necessary to remove the trailing dot. You can
adjust the distance with `textdistance` key.